# Decrypt in C# a password encrypted in Java

Tags: java, c#, encryption, cryptography

The Openbravo software and its derivatives (e.g. unicentaopos) have the following implementation of encryption to store the database password in a plain configuration file.

```
package com.openbravo.pos.util;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;

/**
 *
 * @author JG uniCenta
 */
public class AltEncrypter {

    private Cipher cipherDecrypt;
    private Cipher cipherEncrypt;

    /** Creates a new instance of Encrypter
     * @param passPhrase */
    public AltEncrypter(String passPhrase) {

        try {
            SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            sr.setSeed(passPhrase.getBytes("UTF8"));
            KeyGenerator kGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESEDE");
            kGen.init(168, sr);
            Key key = kGen.generateKey();

            cipherEncrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DESEDE/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipherEncrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

            cipherDecrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DESEDE/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipherDecrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param str
     * @return
     */
    public String encrypt(String str) {
        try {
            return StringUtils.byte2hex(cipherEncrypt.doFinal(str.getBytes("UTF8")));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param str
     * @return
     */
    public String decrypt(String str) {
        try {
            return new String(cipherDecrypt.doFinal(StringUtils.hex2byte(str)), "UTF8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }    
}
```

To encrypt, the following is used (only the password is encrypted):

```
 config.setProperty("db.user", jtxtDbUser.getText());
        AltEncrypter cypher = new AltEncrypter("cypherkey" + jtxtDbUser.getText());       
        config.setProperty("db.password", "crypt:" + cypher.encrypt(new String(jtxtDbPassword.getPassword())));
```

To decrypt, the following is used:

```
  String sDBUser = m_App.getProperties().getProperty("db.user");
  String sDBPassword = m_App.getProperties().getProperty("db.password");
  if (sDBUser != null && sDBPassword != null && sDBPassword.startsWith("crypt:")) {
     AltEncrypter cypher = new AltEncrypter("cypherkey" + sDBUser);
     sDBPassword = cypher.decrypt(sDBPassword.substring(6));
   }
```

I am working on an independent software module in C# and I'd like to read the database password from that configuration file. Any advice on how to accomplish this?

From analyzing the code, I can deduce that:

1. The password "encryption" is reversible because it is later used in the software to build database connection strings.
2. The base passphrase is "cypherkey" + username
3. The password is stored in the plain file with the format

> db.password=crypt:XXX

where XXX is the encrypted password.

Please help me to work out how to decrypt the password. Help on actually reading the plain file is not necessary. Please assume that I already have stored the username and encrypted password (without the "crypt:" part) in variables in the C# program.

I've been trying to modify the existing examples on similar question but they focus on AES and so far I have not been successful with this.

Basically, the following function in C# should be built:

```
private string DecryptPassword(string username, string encryptedPassword)
```

How would I do this?

The software is open source and can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unicentaopos/files/)

One test case: `DecryptPassword("mark", "19215E9576DE6A96D5F03FE1D3073DCC")` should return the password `getmeback`. The base passphrase would be `cypherkeymark`. I have tested in different machines and the "hashed" password is always the same using the same username.

Comment: SHA1 is a one-way hash; not a reversible crypto-system.

Comment: This thing is more complicated than that, it uses a pseudo random number generator using SHA1 which is seeded with the UTF-8 encoding of the password to derive a 168-bit key, then tripple DES in Encrypt-Decrypt-Encrypt ("EDE") mode is used for encryption (this is indeed reversible) of the `str` parameter. If an equivalent to `SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");` doesn't exist in C#, you're screwed. Once you have that, all you need is to derive the original key again and run the `encryptedPassword` through a tripple-DES-decryption. If you don't mind can you publish some test data for testing?

Comment: Indeed, it seems that this is not SHA1, but a custom encrypt/decrypt method instead. Title edited. I know the password is reversible since it is used later in the original software to build the database connection string. The software is open source and can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unicentaopos/files/) One test case: `DecryptPassword("mark", "19215E9576DE6A96D5F03FE1D3073DCC")` should return the password `getmeback`. The base passphrase would be "cypherkeymark". I have tested in different machines and the "hashed" password is always the same for the same username.

Comment: Just a small correction to your comment @MaximilianGerhardt: "it uses a pseudo random number generator using SHA1 which is seeded with the UTF-8 encoding of the **passphrase** to derive a 168-bit key".

Answer (score 3):

The method used by `AltEncrypter` to derive a key from the password is terrible. This approach should *not* be used.

First of all, it's not secure. A key derivation algorithm is not secure unless it is computationally intensive. Instead, use an algorithm like scrypt, bcrypt, or PBKDF2.

Second, the SHA1PRNG algorithm is not well defined. Saying, "it uses SHA-1" isn't sufficient. How often is a hash performed? It's not standardized; you won't be able to request a "SHA1PRNG" on another platform (like .Net), and get the same output.

So, scrap this encryption method and use something easy and secure, written and maintained by knowledgeable people.

Unfortunately, the problems don't end there. The `AltEncrypter` utility is used in the worst way possible, with a key that isn't secret, to reversibly encrypt an authentication password. This is not secure at all. It allows an attacker to decrypt user passwords and use them against the user's accounts on other systems.

It's almost like the author of this system *wanted* to create a security catastrophe.

Comment: I was so aghast, I looked up this package. Apparently the "pos" package is for "point-of-sale." That's not what I was thinking.

Comment: The quote `SHA1PRNG is a proprietary algorithm supplied by Sun.` (from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21205388) completes that this can hardly be done in C# unless someone reverse-engineers the java code. Indeed, in this setting, this is more an encoding of the password with known parameters rather than encryption, you explained the giant security problem nicely, +1. Edit: Or not, after some googling I've found a source code reference (https://opensource.apple.com/source/gcc3/gcc3-1161/libjava/gnu/java/security/provider/SHA1PRNG.java), if someone ports this to C#, all's good.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, @erickson. I have added more information to the question (software source and a test case). I would like to take your suggestion of scraping this encryption method, but sadly I am not in charge for that project. I am only trying to do a C# module that extends inventory functionality and I require to read the password to build the database connection string. I didn't do it in Java because that is not exactly my stronghold.

Answer (score 1):

This is a note. I cannot add comments but I think that the algorithm used to encrypt is not SHA1. It is "DESEDE/ECB/PKCS5Padding" look at the line where the cipher to encrypt is created (obtained) 
**cipherEncrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DESEDE/ECB/PKCS5Padding");**

SHA1PRNG is a pseudo-random number generator used to generate a first random number used into the encryption process in order to generate "different" encryptions even when the same *plain text* is encrypted.

Another important thing is the key used to encrypt, I mean:

```
 KeyGenerator kGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESEDE");
 kGen.init(168, sr);
 Key key = kGen.generateKey(); <-- this key
```

this key is used to encrypt and decrypt but I cannot see where it is stored. I mean that it is regenerated every time. It should be stored and retrieved from somewhere and not regenerated because, it is not possible to decrypt any cipher text if it is not used the same key.

Comment: The pseudo number generator is always initiated with the username so for one user you will always get the same key, that is farther used for encrypting/decrypting password.

Comment: Exactly, as @MJar said. If you take a look to the class signature `public AltEncrypter(String passPhrase)`, the passPhrase that is sent when encrypting is just `cypherkey` + username. So if the username is `mark`, then the passPhrase parameter that is sent is `cypherkeymark`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer using some workarounds.

I've tried reimplementing the `SHA1PRNG` provided the GNU implementation (which is [opensource](https://opensource.apple.com/source/gcc3/gcc3-1161/libjava/gnu/java/security/provider/SHA1PRNG.java)), but it doesn't give the same results as the properitary SUN implementation (so either they're different or I have implemented it in a wrong way). So I've implemented a workaround: Call a java-program to derive the key for us. Yes, this is very cheap, but a working work-around for the time being. If someone sees the mistake in my SHA1PRNG implementation, let me know.

So first, here's a simple Java program which will derive a 168-bit key given a seed using the `SHA1PRNG` generator. Simply outputs it on `stdout`, space seperated.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;

public class PasswordDeriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        if(args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("You need to give the seed as the first argument.");
            return;
        }
        //Use Java to generate the key used for encryption and decryption.
        String passPhrase = args[args.length-1];

        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(passPhrase.getBytes("UTF8"));
        KeyGenerator kGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESEDE");
        kGen.init(168, sr);
        Key key = kGen.generateKey();

        //Key is generated, now output it. 
        //System.out.println("Format: " + key.getFormat());
        byte[] k = key.getEncoded();
        for(int i=0; i < k.length; i++){
            System.out.print(String.format((i == k.length - 1) ? "%X" : "%X ", k[i]));
        }        
    }
}
```

This is saved as `PasswordDeriver.java`, compiled using `javac <file>` and the resulting `PasswordDeriver.class` is then placed in the same folder as this compiled program: (The actual C# program)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace OpenbravoDecrypter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var decrypted = Decrypt("19215E9576DE6A96D5F03FE1D3073DCC", "mark");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string Decrypt(string ciphertext, string username)
        {
            //Ciphertext is given as a hex string, convert it back to bytes
            if(ciphertext.Length % 2 == 1) ciphertext = "0" + ciphertext; //pad a zero left is necessary
            byte[] ciphertext_bytes = new byte[ciphertext.Length / 2];
            for(int i=0; i < ciphertext.Length; i+=2)
                ciphertext_bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(ciphertext.Substring(i, 2), 16);

            //Get an instance of a tripple-des descryption
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();        
            tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; //ECB as Cipher Mode
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; //PKCS7 padding (same as PKCS5, good enough)

            byte[] key_bytes = DeriveKeyWorkAround(username);
            Console.WriteLine("Derived Key: " + BitConverter.ToString(key_bytes));
            //Start the decryption, give it the key, and null for the IV.
            var decryptor = tdes.CreateDecryptor(key_bytes, null);
            //Decrypt it.
            var plain = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(ciphertext_bytes, 0, ciphertext_bytes.Length);

            //Output the result as hex string and as UTF8 encoded string
            Console.WriteLine("Plaintext Bytes: " + BitConverter.ToString(plain));
            var s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plain);
            Console.WriteLine("Plaintext UTF-8: " + s);
            return s;
        }

        /* Work around the fact that we don't have a C# implementation of SHA1PRNG by calling into a custom-prepared java file..*/
        static byte[] DeriveKeyWorkAround(string username)
        {
            username = "cypherkey" + username;
            string procOutput = "";
            //Invoke java on our file
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c java PasswordDeriver \"" + username + "\"";
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.OutputDataReceived += (e, d) => procOutput += d.Data;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.Start();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            p.WaitForExit();

            //Convert it back
            byte[] key = procOutput.Split(' ').Select(hex => Convert.ToByte(hex, 16)).ToArray();

            return key;
        }


        /* This function copies the functionality of the GNU Implementation of SHA1PRNG. 
         * Currently, it's broken, meaning that it doesn't produce the same output as the SUN implenetation of SHA1PRNG.
         * Case 1: the GNU implementation is the same as the SUN implementation, and this re-implementation is just wrong somewhere
         * Case 2: the GNU implementation is not the same the SUN implementation, therefore you'd need to reverse engineer some existing
         * SUN implementation and correct this method. 
       */
        static byte[] DeriveKey(string username)
        {
            //adjust
            username = "cypherkey" + username;
            byte[] user = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username);
            //Do SHA1 magic
            var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            var seed = new byte[20];
            byte[] data = new byte[40];
            int seedpos = 0;
            int datapos = 0;

            //init stuff
            byte[] digestdata;
            digestdata = sha1.ComputeHash(data);
            Array.Copy(digestdata, 0, data, 0, 20);

            /* seeding part */
            for (int i=0; i < user.Length; i++)
            {
                seed[seedpos++ % 20] ^= user[i];
            }
            seedpos %= 20;

            /* Generate output bytes */
            byte[] bytes = new byte[24]; //we need 24 bytes (= 192 bit / 8)

            int loc = 0;
            while (loc < bytes.Length)
            {
                int copy = Math.Min(bytes.Length - loc, 20 - datapos);

                if (copy > 0)
                {
                    Array.Copy(data, datapos, bytes, loc, copy);
                    datapos += copy;
                    loc += copy;
                }
                else
                {
                    // No data ready for copying, so refill our buffer.
                    Array.Copy(seed, 0, data, 20, 20);
                    byte[] digestdata2 = sha1.ComputeHash(data);
                    Array.Copy(digestdata2, 0, data, 0, 20);
                    datapos = 0;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("GENERATED KEY:\n");
            for(int i=0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(bytes[i].ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0'));
            }

            return bytes;
        } 
    }
}
```

You can see the standard stuff such as initializing a tripple-DES cryptoprovider, giving it a key and computing the decryption of the ciphertext in there. It also contains the currently broken implementation of the `SHA1PRNG` and the workaround. Given that `java` is in the `PATH` of the current environment variable, this program produces the output:

> Derived Key: 86-EF-C1-F2-2F-97-D3-F1-34-49-23-89-E3-EC-29-80-02-92-52-40-49-5D-CD-C1
>
> Plaintext Bytes: 67-65-74-6D-65-62-61-63-6B
>
> Plaintext UTF-8: getmeback

So, here you have the decrypt function (encrypting it would the same, just change `.CreateDecryptor()` to `.CreateEncryptor()`). If you forget about the code doing the key derivation, the decryption code does its work in only ~20 lines of code. So in review, my answer is a starting point for others who want to make this solution 100% C#. Hope this helps.

Comment: Should the OP take this approach, then perhaps a better performing alternative (as compared to creating a new process) would be to have a program that listens on a [socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) and accepts pass phrase as requests and returns the encoded key in response .